# Temporal table Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

i'm working with google sheet as primary database.
The data is sent and stored to 2 sheets where the user can interact with it.
The user can also modify the data.
The target is to track all changes from the 2 sheets and to copy the changes to another sheets.
If sheet 1 is modified, the edited row will be copied to HistoricalSheet 1 and same for sheet 2.
when the data will be copied, it will be accompanied with a timestamp and the userID, who modified the sheet.

My issue is that when retrieving the row range, it is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "hh:mm:ss dd MMMM yyyy")
  var userID = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];

  if(sourceSheet.getSheetName() == 'Sheet1'){
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('HistoricalSheet 1');
    targetSheet.appendRow([timeStamp,userID,rowValues]);
  } else if(sourceSheet.getSheetName() == 'Sheet2'){
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('HistoricalSheet 2');
    targetSheet.appendRow([timeStamp,userID,rowValues]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The edited row is e.range.rowStart the column is e.range.columnStart

Comment: Please add the textual error message.

Comment: About `My issue is that when retrieving the row range, it is undefined.`, when I saw your script, when a cell is edited, the data range of the edited row is retrieved. So I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can I ask you about the method for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: The onEdit works now based on this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes). the issue now that the  timestamp, the userid are append but the values is in form of [Ljava.lang.Object;@34c3ed94 in a cell only.

The values aren't append to the rest of the row.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `The onEdit works now based on this link. the issue now that the timestamp, the userid are append but the values is in form of [Ljava.lang.Object;@34c3ed94 in a cell only. The values aren't append to the rest of the row.`  in your reply, I understood that your issue of `My issue is that when retrieving the row range, it is undefined.` was resolved.

About your current issue, I think that the reason for your issue is due to `rowValues` is an array. So in this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "hh:mm:ss dd MMMM yyyy")
  var userID = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
  var obj = { "Sheet1": "HistoricalSheet 1", "Sheet2": "HistoricalSheet 2" };
  var sheetName = sourceSheet.getSheetName();
  if (!obj[sheetName]) return;
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName(obj[sheetName]);
  targetSheet.appendRow([timeStamp, userID, ...rowValues]); // targetSheet.appendRow([timeStamp, userID, rowValues.join(",")]);
}
```

- In this modification, the edited row is put to the specification sheet in another Spreadsheet using an object for searching the sheet name. By this, I thought that the script can be simpler a little.
- And, by `targetSheet.appendRow([timeStamp, userID, ...rowValues])`, the edited row is put to a row.
- If you want to put the row values into one cell, please modify to `targetSheet.appendRow([timeStamp, userID, rowValues.join(",")])`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, I modified the function name from `onEdit` to `installedOnEdit`. Because when `SpreadsheetApp.openById` is used, it is required to use the installable OnEdit trigger. But, when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function `onEdit`, `onEdit` is run by both the simple trigger and the installable trigger with asyncrhonous process. So, I modified the function name. So, please install the installable OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`, and test it again.

#### References:

- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Hello @Tanaike thanks for your response, it works really fine. I also managed to append the row by the use of index in the array ( `rowValues[0],rowValues[1],rowValues[2],rowValues[3]` ) but yours is more direct and simple to understand. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @P.J Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "hh:mm:ss dd MMMM yyyy")
  const uid = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getValues()[0];
  if(sh.getSheetName() == 'Sheet1'){
    let tsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('HistoricalSheet 1');
    tsh.appendRow([ts,uid,vs]);
  } else if(sh.getSheetName() == 'Sheet2'){
    let targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('HistoricalSheet 2');
    targetSheet.appendRow([ts,uid,vs]);
    }
  }
```